# Back ground Subtraction class pros please answer

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, background-subtraction, pixel-manipulation

Can someone define the class BackgroundSubtractorMOG2.What does history(argument for the BackgroundSubtractor class mean).Is some technique like code books available using BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 class??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a new class from scratch and that solved the problem.Use the accumulator and frame subtraction methods to recreate the backgoundSubtractorMOG and i developed my own codebook model.

Comment: Even though making a codebook model was possible it didn't turn out to be helpful for detecting hand in changing backgrounds does anyone have a better suggestion for that